# Flutters Just Audio Plugin - Make the background transparent?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, just-audio

I'd got Flutter's Just_Audio player overlayed on top of my current stack. But the background is white. I need it to be transparent so that only the buttons and slider shows. So far I have been unable to find where I can set the background to transparent. Does anybody know? Here's a sample of some of the code;

```
class ControlButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final AudioPlayer player;

  ControlButtons(this.player);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
          stream: player.playerStateStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final playerState = snapshot.data;
            final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
            final playing = playerState?.playing;
            if (processingState == ProcessingState.loading ||
                processingState == ProcessingState.buffering) {
              return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: 64.0,
                height: 64.0,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (playing != true) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: player.play,
              );
            } else if (processingState != ProcessingState.completed) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: player.pause,
              );
            } else {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
                iconSize: 64.0,
                onPressed: () => player.seek(Duration.zero,
                    index: player.effectiveIndices!.first),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SeekBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration duration;
  final Duration position;
  final Duration bufferedPosition;
  final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChanged;
  final ValueChanged<Duration>? onChangeEnd;

  SeekBar({
    required this.duration,
    required this.position,
    required this.bufferedPosition,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onChangeEnd,
  });

  @override
  _SeekBarState createState() => _SeekBarState();
}

class _SeekBarState extends State<SeekBar> {
  double? _dragValue;
  late SliderThemeData _sliderThemeData;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _sliderThemeData = SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        trackHeight: 2.0
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          SliderTheme(
            data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
              thumbShape: HiddenThumbComponentShape(),
              activeTrackColor: Colors.blue.shade100,
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
            ),
            child: ExcludeSemantics(
              child: Slider(
                min: 0.0,
                max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                value: widget.bufferedPosition.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _dragValue = value;
                  });
                  if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                    widget.onChanged!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                  }
                },
                onChangeEnd: (value) {
                  if (widget.onChangeEnd != null) {
                    widget.onChangeEnd!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                  }
                  _dragValue = null;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliderTheme(
            data: _sliderThemeData.copyWith(
              inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: Slider(
              min: 0.0,
              max: widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
              value: min(_dragValue ?? widget.position.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                  widget.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _dragValue = value;
                });
                if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                  widget.onChanged!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                }
              },
              onChangeEnd: (value) {
                if (widget.onChangeEnd != null) {
                  widget.onChangeEnd!(Duration(milliseconds: value.round()));
                }
                _dragValue = null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 16.0,
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: Text(
                RegExp(r'((^0*[1-9]\d*:)?\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d+$')
                    .firstMatch("$_remaining")
                    ?.group(1) ??
                    '$_remaining',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Duration get _remaining => widget.duration - widget.position;
}

class HiddenThumbComponentShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) => Size.zero;

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
        required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
        required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
        required bool isDiscrete,
        required TextPainter labelPainter,
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        required double value,
        required double textScaleFactor,
        required Size sizeWithOverflow,
      }) {}
}

class PositionData {
  final Duration position;
  final Duration bufferedPosition;

  PositionData(this.position, this.bufferedPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can do this;

```
  MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor:Colors.transparent,
```